# Android Studio Saving Files API>25?

Tags: android, file

I hope someone can help me, because I have this problem now quite long and searched for a lot of questions and answers, but they don't help me, because I don't find my Error.... 
Saving files at my App (Android Studio is making problems with API>25)

Here's the Code:

```
String test = "Das ist nur ein Test für Api 25";
    File Root1 = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    File Root1Dir = new File(Root1.getAbsolutePath() + "/Setups");
    Log.i("Info Data Directory", Root1.getAbsolutePath());
    File Root2 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File Root2Dir = new File(Root2.getAbsolutePath() + "/Setups");
    Log.i("Info ExternalStorage", Root2.getAbsolutePath());
    Root1Dir.mkdirs();


    Root2Dir.mkdirs();
    File file1Write = new File(Root1Dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/test.txt");
    File file2Write = new File(Root2Dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/test.txt");




    try {
        FileOutputStream fOs = new FileOutputStream(file1Write);
        fOs.write(test.getBytes());
        fOs.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("Error", "File1 failed data Directory");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fOs = new FileOutputStream(file2Write);
        fOs.write(test.getBytes());
        fOs.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("Error", "File1 failed emulated Directory");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

This method is called on a Button Click. I also Have the Permissions and even ask them right away after starting the Activity.

> Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/Setups/test.txt (No such
>   file or directory)

Comment: Can you show me the Manifest file

Comment: `/data/Setups/test.txt (No such file or directory)` That is an impossible directory. Even if it would exist you would not have access. Only on a rooted device with a suitable app. But it will not exist.

Comment: `File Root1 = Environment.getDataDirectory();`. Please tell us what value `Root1.getAbso;utePath()` delivers. You just mess up all. Also tell the value for `RootDir1.getAbsolutePath()`.

Comment: `Root1Dir.mkdirs();`. Two programming mistakes. First: Only call mkdirs() if the directory does not exist yet. Second: check the return value of mkdirs() as when it fails it will return false. In that case you should display a toast to the user telling so. And return. It makes little sense to contine with the code then.

Comment: `(Android Studio is making problems with API>25) ` Andorid Studio? Dont think so! Your app will make problems. And on all devices. On all versions. You cannot use getDataDirectory() in this way. Never. Nowhere.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the comments, sorry i described it bad, it was my first question here. @greenaps thanks for the help! But when i only use getExternalStorageDirectory() and ask if a folder already exists, I still have problems showing the files on the Device Monitor, even if it is working on my phone. According to Android Studio it is saved at /storage/emulated/0, but there are no files when i explore it with the device monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `getDataDirectory()`.

Instead use `getFilesDir()`.